# Boostrap Make a icon span over two rows

Tags: bootstrap-4

I have this code:

```
 <div class="col-sm-3">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class = "row">
                            <div class = "col-sm-6">
                                <h1 class="card-title float-left">5 l </h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class = "col-sm-6">
                                <h1> <i class="mt-1 fa fa-tint float-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="card-text">Ölstand in Liter   </p>   
                        
                        
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
```

Which looks like this:

[image: Boostrap Card]

and i want the drop to span over "5l" and "Ölstand in Liter".
I know I can somehow create neated columns but I can't figure out how to do it right.

Comment: Explain more, please.

Comment: the big drop icon next to 5l should be bigger and should also be next to the text under 5l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body">
            <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-around align-items-start">
                    <h1 class="card-title">5 l </h1>
                    <p class="card-text">Ölstand in Liter   </p>
                </div>
                <h1><i class="fa fa-tint pt-3" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 1.5em;"></i></h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can adjust the icon size by setting it's font-size